# Problems Horizontal / Vertical Layout Android App

Tags: android

I´m trying to code my first android-app. I read a lot, but I have problems with the layout.
What is wrong in both xml?
For a better understanding, I have made a picture:[image: pic]

My XML for main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:orientation="vertical" >



<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/imageView1"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_weight="2.5"

    android:contentDescription="@string/upload"

    android:scaleType="fitCenter"

    android:visibility="visible" />



<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="0dp"

    android:layout_weight="4"

    android:gravity="center"

    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <Button

        android:id="@+id/btnShoot"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"

        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"

        android:text="@string/shoot_again" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

for main.xml in the folder layout-land, If i switch to the landscape-Mode the app crashes:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:orientation="horizontal" >



<Button

    android:id="@+id/btnShoot"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"

    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"

    android:text="@string/shoot" />



<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/imageView1"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:contentDescription="@string/upload"

    android:scaleType="fitCenter"

    android:visibility="visible" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When you say 'it crashes', what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just looking at your XML, there are a few issues:

Portrait XML:

```
< ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2.5"
```

Here, you've set both a weight and a height - in a `LinearLayout` you can't have both. Either you set the height yourself, or you give it a height of `0dp` and a weight, then let the `LinearLayout` assign the height. As for why it's rotated, the image itself might be rotated in your resources.

Horizontal XML:

- Your root `LinearLayout` still needs to have a `vertical` orientation
- Your ImageView needs to be declared above your Button

What's happening is that a) it's horizontal, b) your button is getting put on first, and c) your button has a `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, which means the `ImageView` has nowhere to be put, as your Button is already taking up all of the space on screen (can you see why this is case?)

Make these changes, then update your question as appropriate, as I think that your problems will have changed